# What are the most interesting/useful new things in Perl 5.12?

Tags: perl

I remember quickly adopting `given .. when`, `say`, `//`, and the smart matching operator when Perl 5.10 came around.

What do you consider the most useful fixes and features introduced with Perl 5.12.0?

Comment: This should be community wiki

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512047/is-there-anything-exciting-in-perl-5-11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my favourite feature by far:

```
use 5.012; # enables 'use strict' implicitly!
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix, Alexandr!

Answer (score 6):

Raw data:

- The [full list of changes](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod)
- [Incompatibility changes](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Potentially_Incompatible_Changes)

Interesting:

- [Regexps are now first class](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#___top)
- [Pluggable keywords](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Pluggable_keywords)
- [New syntax allows developers to specify package version numbers directly in "package" statements](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#New_package_NAME_VERSION_syntax)
- **Perl now warns the user about the use of deprecated features by default.**

Wonderful:

Not sure if any of the info is new, but [perlperf - Perl Performance and Optimization Techniques](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perlperf.pod) was added to documentation!!!

Useful:

- DTRACE (some) support!
- `\N` regex escape
- [`...` (aka Yada Yada) operator](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#The_..._operator)
- [Y2038 Compliance - Perl now has a better sense of time and will be able to keep accurate time well past the "Y2038" barrier.](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#___top)

Comment: BTW, above picks are just my opinion. YMMV obviously :)

Answer (score 6):

`while( readdir $dir ){}` now works a lot more like `while( readline $file ){}`.

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e'while( readline $f ){}'
```

```
while (defined($_ = <$f>)) {
    ();
}
```

<sub>`<$f>` is the same as `readline $f`</sub>

---

This is how Perl versions prior to v5.11.2 have been handling `while( readdir $dir ){}`

```
perl-5.10 -MO=Deparse -e'while( readdir $d ){}'
```

```
while (readdir $d) {
    ();
}
```

It is worth noting that the above will fail to work correctly if there is a file, or directory with the name of `0`. Which doesn't matter that much since it doesn't do anything useful anyway.

---

In Perl version 5.11.2 there was a patch added that brought it more into line with the handling of `while( readline $file ){...}`.

```
perl-5.12.0 -MO=Deparse -e'while( readdir $d ){}'
```

```
while (defined($_ = readdir $d)) {
    ();
}
```

---

I would like to note that **I** was the one who provided that patch. It was the first thing I have ever tried to fix in the Perl core. So it was also the first patch I wrote, that made it into Perl.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of [Yada Yada](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perlop.pod#Yada_Yada_Operator___), although time will tell if it is actually useful.

Answer (score 3):

There's some subtle but non-trivial improvements that will make Portable (flash drive) Perl distributions work better (or at all).

Perl also now has support for 64-bit on Windows with GCC, so Strawberry Perl 64-bit should come out soon.